# On Similar Matrices' Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Say we have $A,B,C,D\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ and $B$ are conjugates,$C$ and $D$ are conjugates, can we find a matrix $P$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$ and $C=PDP^{-1}$?

Comment: No, we cannot. Try to find counterexamples with $n=2$.

Comment: In general no.  When that property does hold for diagonalizing, it is called diagonalizing a set of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

No. The desired property implies that $AC$ is similar to $BD$, but this is not a consequence of the similarities between $A$ and $B$ and between $C$ and $D$. E.g. consider
$$
A=B=C=\pmatrix{1\\ &0},\ D=\pmatrix{0\\ &1}.
$$
Then $A$ is similar to $B$ and $C$ is similar to $D$, but $AC\ne0$ is not similar to $BD=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you elaborate on how $AC$ is similar to $BD$ can yield the desired property?

Comment: @flypig It cannot. It is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

Comment: I see, thank you!